# vaadin UI call from callback

Tags: java, user-interface, callback, vaadin

i am trying to build a 2-step process using vaadin. I created a view that holds my 2 main components (extends Div) which are displayed alternately.

to change from one of the main components to the other i have a ComboBox that i use for searching and therefore implemented a CallbackDataProvider, like seen below.

```
ComboBox<ResponsePartSearchResult> cmbPartSearch = new ComboBox<>();
CallbackDataProvider<ResponsePartSearchResult, String> provider = new CallbackDataProvider<ResponsePartSearchResult, String>(
                query -> {
                    // fetch callback
                }, query -> {
                    // retrieve count
                });
```

The user is supposed to search for parts, get a list, and should be able to click on one of the results. this result is then displayed in the ComboBox. In another text field he has to add more info and click on a Button, in order to proceed. The Button's ClickListener retrieves the value from the ComboBox and the second TextField and sends it to a private method:

```
ResponsePartSearchResult value = cmbPartSearch.getValue(); 
value.q = txtPartSerial.getValue();
proceedToStepTwo(value)
```

BUT! If the user pastes a valid ID, the result coming back from the backend contains a certain flag, showing that this part was retrieved by its ID and with all required additional info. In this case the user is supposed to be directly "redirected" to the second main component, whithout the need to click the Button.

In this case I call the method `proceedToStepTwo` within the "fetch callback".

For the first case everything is running smoothly so far. For the second case, however, the 2nd main component and all it's UI elements are shown, but in order to click on something, whether it is a button or a checkbox, i need a double click. 
It's a very strange behaviour without any error message. When I click on a Button (I added a sysout to a ClickListener) on that 2nd main component my RequestLoggingFilter shows a few of the following lines:

```
After request [uri=/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=0;client=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;session= ...]
```

but not the content of the sysout. It only shows the content (and a few of the Logging lines above) when i doubleclick.
This shows that the Button reacts, but not entirely.

When I just let the fetch callback fill the ComboBox and TextFields and click the Button manually, it works again. But I want to get rid of the separate manual step.

I **assume** when I'm inside of that callback method, I need to call `proceedToStepTwo` differently, but how? Any ideas or experiences? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
When i debug and set a breakpoint into the method proceedToStepTwo() the UI will behave expectedly. **However** when i remove the breakpoint again and put a Thread.sleep(1000) in there, nothing changes and i cannot properly click the UI elements.